# How to add required profile data for reservation system

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am building a reservation system in django 2 and python 3 where you can rent Tools. The user register with First and Last Name as well as email. I extended the django user model and created a model called 'profile' which has the following fields:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    matrnr = models.CharField(max_length=6, validators=[MinLengthValidator(6), MaxLengthValidator(6)], default='', blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=6, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5), MaxLengthValidator(5)], default='', blank=True, null=True)
    homephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default='', null=True)
    mobilephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default='', null=True)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='', null=True)
    driverlicense_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='', null=True)
```

There is a page with the borrowable tools, with a "Reserve" button next to each item. If the user now clicks on this button, it should first be checked whether the user has already filled in his profile data or not. If not, the user has to fill them in before he can borrow something.

How can I achieve that? I am clueless as I am a beginner.

This is the table where I list all the tools:

```
{% block title %}Tool List{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

    <p> Here you see all the borrowable tools  </p>




    {% for instance in toollist %}
        <table border="3" cellspacing="5">
          <colgroup>
            <col width="600">
            <col width="100">
            <col width="180">
          </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td><b>{{ instance.tool_name }}</b></td>
                <td>{{ instance.tool_status }}</td>
                    {% if instance.tool_status == 1 %}
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            {%  if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <a href="{% url 'reservation' %}">Reserve now</a>

                            {% else %}
                                <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login for reservation</a>
                         </td>
                            {% endif %}
                    {% elif instance.tool_status == 0 %}
                        <td rowspan="2"> Not available </td>
                    {% endif %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">{{ instance.tool_text }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
```

Here is my signup view:

```
def signup(request):                
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Bestätige deine Registrierung beim Ausleihsystem'
            message = render_to_string('registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(), 
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER       
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            recipient_list = [email]
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})

def account_activation_sent(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/account_activation_sent.html')


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:                                                
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):  
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/account_activation_invalid.html')


def profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', args)
```

And this is the edit_profile view:

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'registration/edit_profile.html', {
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```